# Magento 2 Add dropdown list to shipping method

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, shipping-methods

I develop shipping method for some logistic company. This company has many offices where customer can get his order. I can get offices list by сity in **API** but i don't now how better represent this step?

For now i just set new `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method`
  to every  office in town, in big town it's **count > 100** and i think it's not very good to set 100 lines in checkout.

It will be public module for different checkout design so how can I render near selected my shipping method some dropdown list with list of offices and set price and method after user select one.

Comment: @Zefiryn I found this post very interesting, but I have a question, if I have to show in the select not the offices but the stores that are inside Amasty's module, how I would do the second part of your post? I mean: where is the place where I call the helper of Amasty to fill up the xml component "vendor_carrier_form"? Thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135910)

Comment: this is not a new question but a variation of the way used by Zefiryn... because I used the first part of the post as it is

Answer (score 22):

Magento checkout does not support any kind of form for shipping method additional data. But it provides `shippingAdditional` block in the checkout which can be used for this. The following solution will work for standard magento checkout.

First let's prepare our container where we can put some form. To do this create a file in `view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="vendor_carrier_form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/form</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create a file in `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/form.js` which will render a knockout template. Its content looks like this

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/office-service',
    'mage/translate',
], function ($, ko, Component, quote, shippingService, officeService, t) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/shipping/form'
        },

        initialize: function (config) {
            this.offices = ko.observableArray();
            this.selectedOffice = ko.observable();
            this._super();
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            this._super();

            this.showOfficeSelection = ko.computed(function() {
                return this.ofices().length != 0
            }, this);

            this.selectedMethod = ko.computed(function() {
                var method = quote.shippingMethod();
                var selectedMethod = method != null ? method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code : null;
                return selectedMethod;
            }, this);

            quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(function(method) {
                var selectedMethod = method != null ? method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code : null;
                if (selectedMethod == 'carrier_method') {
                    this.reloadOffices();
                }
            }, this);

            this.selectedOffice.subscribe(function(office) {
                if (quote.shippingAddress().extensionAttributes == undefined) {
                    quote.shippingAddress().extensionAttributes = {};
                }
                quote.shippingAddress().extensionAttributes.carrier_office = office;
            });


            return this;
        },

        setOfficeList: function(list) {
            this.offices(list);
        },

        reloadOffices: function() {
            officeService.getOfficeList(quote.shippingAddress(), this);
            var defaultOffice = this.offices()[0];
            if (defaultOffice) {
                this.selectedOffice(defaultOffice);
            }
        },

        getOffice: function() {
            var office;
            if (this.selectedOffice()) {
                for (var i in this.offices()) {
                    var m = this.offices()[i];
                    if (m.name == this.selectedOffice()) {
                        office = m;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                office = this.offices()[0];
            }

            return office;
        },

        initSelector: function() {
            var startOffice = this.getOffice();
        }
    });
});
```

This file uses knockout template which should be placed in `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping/form.html`

```
<div id="carrier-office-list-wrapper" data-bind="visible: selectedMethod() == 'carrier_method'">
    <p data-bind="visible: !showOfficeSelection(), i18n: 'Please provide postcode to see nearest offices'"></p>
    <div data-bind="visible: showOfficeSelection()">
        <p>
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Select pickup office.'"></span>
        </p>
        <select id="carrier-office-list" data-bind="options: offices(),
                                            value: selectedOffice,
                                            optionsValue: 'name',
                                            optionsText: function(item){return item.location + ' (' + item.name +')';}">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

We have now a select field that will be visible when our method (defined by its code) will be selected in the shipping methods table. Time to fill it with some options. Since values are dependent on the address the best way is to create rest endpoint that will provide available options. In `Vendor/Module/etc/webapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

    <!-- Managing Office List on Checkout page -->
    <route url="/V1/module/get-office-list/:postcode/:city" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\OfficeManagementInterface" method="fetchOffices"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Now define interface in `Vendor/Module/Api/OfficeManagementInterface.php` as

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Api;

interface OfficeManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * Find offices for the customer
     *
     * @param string $postcode
     * @param string $city
     * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\OfficeInterface[]
     */
    public function fetchOffices($postcode, $city);
}
```

Define interface for office data in `Vendor\Module\Api\Data\OfficeInterface.php`. This interface will be used by webapi module to filter data for the output so you need to define whatever you need to add into the response.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Api\Data;

/**
 * Office Interface
 */
interface OfficeInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocation();
}
```

Time for actual classes. Start with creating preferences for all interfaces in `Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\OfficeManagementInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\OfficeManagement" />
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\Data\OfficeInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Office" />
</config>
```

Now create `Vendor\Module\Model\OfficeManagement.php` class that will actually do the logic of fetching the data.

```
namespace Vednor\Module\Model;

use Vednor\Module\Api\OfficeManagementInterface;
use Vednor\Module\Api\Data\OfficeInterfaceFactory;

class OfficeManagement implements OfficeManagementInterface
{
    protected $officeFactory;

    /**
     * OfficeManagement constructor.
     * @param OfficeInterfaceFactory $officeInterfaceFactory
     */
    public function __construct(OfficeInterfaceFactory $officeInterfaceFactory)
    {
        $this->officeFactory = $officeInterfaceFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get offices for the given postcode and city
     *
     * @param string $postcode
     * @param string $limit
     * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\OfficeInterface[]
     */
    public function fetchOffices($postcode, $city)
    {
        $result = [];
        for($i = 0, $i < 4;$i++) {
            $office = $this->officeFactory->create();
            $office->setName("Office {$i}");
            $office->setLocation("Address {$i}");
            $result[] = $office;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And finally class for `OfficeInterface` in `Vendor/Module/Model/Office.php`

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Vendor\Module\Api\Data\OfficeInterface;

class Office extends DataObject implements OfficeInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return (string)$this->_getData('name');
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return (string)$this->_getData('location');
    }
}
```

This should show select field and update it when address is changed. But we are missing one more element for frontend manipulation. We need to create function that will call the endpoint. Call to it is already included in `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/form.js` and it is `Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/office-service` class which should go to `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/office-service.js` with the following code:

```
define(
    [
        'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/model/resource-url-manager',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
        'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/model/office-registry',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor'
    ],
    function (resourceUrlManager, quote, customer, storage, shippingService, officeRegistry, errorProcessor) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            /**
             * Get nearest machine list for specified address
             * @param {Object} address
             */
            getOfficeList: function (address, form) {
                shippingService.isLoading(true);
                var cacheKey = address.getCacheKey(),
                    cache = officeRegistry.get(cacheKey),
                    serviceUrl = resourceUrlManager.getUrlForOfficeList(quote);

                if (cache) {
                    form.setOfficeList(cache);
                    shippingService.isLoading(false);
                } else {
                    storage.get(
                        serviceUrl, false
                    ).done(
                        function (result) {
                            officeRegistry.set(cacheKey, result);
                            form.setOfficeList(result);
                        }
                    ).fail(
                        function (response) {
                            errorProcessor.process(response);
                        }
                    ).always(
                        function () {
                            shippingService.isLoading(false);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        };
    }
);
```

It uses 2 more js files. `Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/model/resource-url-manager` creates a url to the endpoint and is pretty simple

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
        'mageUtils'
    ],
    function(customer, quote, urlBuilder, utils) {
        "use strict";
        return {
            getUrlForOfficeList: function(quote, limit) {
                var params = {postcode: quote.shippingAddress().postcode, city: quote.shippingAddress().city};
                var urls = {
                    'default': '/module/get-office-list/:postcode/:city'
                };
                return this.getUrl(urls, params);
            },

            /** Get url for service */
            getUrl: function(urls, urlParams) {
                var url;

                if (utils.isEmpty(urls)) {
                    return 'Provided service call does not exist.';
                }

                if (!utils.isEmpty(urls['default'])) {
                    url = urls['default'];
                } else {
                    url = urls[this.getCheckoutMethod()];
                }
                return urlBuilder.createUrl(url, urlParams);
            },

            getCheckoutMethod: function() {
                return customer.isLoggedIn() ? 'customer' : 'guest';
            }
        };
    }
);
```

`Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/model/office-registry` is a way of keeping result in the local storage. Its code is:

```
define(
    [],
    function() {
        "use strict";
        var cache = [];
        return {
            get: function(addressKey) {
                if (cache[addressKey]) {
                    return cache[addressKey];
                }
                return false;
            },
            set: function(addressKey, data) {
                cache[addressKey] = data;
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Ok, so we should have all working on frontend. But now there is another problem to resolve. Since checkout doesn't know anything about this form it won't send the selection result to the backend. To make this happen we need to use `extension_attributes` feature. This is a way in magento2 to inform the system that some additional data are expected to be in the rest calls. Without it magento would filter out those data and they would never reach the code.

So first in `Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml` define:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="carrier_office" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

This value is already inserted in the request in `form.js` by `this.selectedOffice.subscribe()` definition. So the above configuration will only pass it at the entrance. To fetch it in the code create a plugin  in `Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address">
    <plugin name="inpost-address" type="Vendor\Module\Quote\AddressPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Inside that class

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier;

class AddressPlugin
{
    /**
     * Hook into setShippingMethod.
     * As this is magic function processed by __call method we need to hook around __call
     * to get the name of the called method. after__call does not provide this information.
     *
     * @param Address $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param string $method
     * @param mixed $vars
     * @return Address
     */
    public function around__call($subject, $proceed, $method, $vars)
    {
        $result = $proceed($method, $vars);
        if ($method == 'setShippingMethod'
            && $vars[0] == Carrier::CARRIER_CODE.'_'.Carrier::METHOD_CODE
            && $subject->getExtensionAttributes()
            && $subject->getExtensionAttributes()->getCarrierOffice()
        ) {
            $subject->setCarrierOffice($subject->getExtensionAttributes()->getCarrierOffice());
        }
        elseif (
            $method == 'setShippingMethod'
            && $vars[0] != Carrier::CARRIER_CODE.'_'.Carrier::METHOD_CODE
        ) {
            //reset office when changing shipping method
            $subject->getCarrierOffice(null);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Of course where you will save the value depends entirely on your requirements. The above code would require creating additional column `carrier_office` in `quote_address` and `sales_address` tables and an event (in `Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="copy_carrier_office" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Model\Order" />
    </event>
</config>
```

That would copy data saved in quote address to sales address.

I wrote this for my module for polish carrier InPost so I changed some names which might break the code but I hope this will give you what you need.

[EDIT]

Carrier model asked by @sangan

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\ElementFactory;

class Carrier extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    const CARRIER_CODE = 'mycarier';

    const METHOD_CODE = 'mymethod';

    /** @var string */
    protected $_code = self::CARRIER_CODE;

    /** @var bool */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * Prepare stores to show on frontend
     *
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject|bool|null
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigData('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $price = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee(0);
        $method->setMethod(self::METHOD_CODE);
        $method->setMethodTitle(new Phrase('MyMethod'));
        $method->setPrice($price);
        $method->setCost($price);
        $result->append($method);;

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        $methods = [
            'mymethod' => new Phrase('MyMethod')
        ];
        return $methods;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your extended reply, i’ll try to solve my issue using your method and will reply with the result these days.

Comment: @Zefiryn                                                                                                                 I have created a custom shipping method, below it will display a dropdown having shipping account numbers of customer(there is a custom customer attribute created) so if I have to display this dropdown how much percent of your code will be helpful? What should I pick up from the code you provided?

Comment: @shireen I would say around 70%. You need to change the part where it fetches machines to account numbers. So api definition will be slighlty diferent and js part of it

Comment: i have tried this module ...but its not showing any changes so please share the working module.if any

Comment: after adding successful module ..in checkout ajax loading continuously.. in console error showing like below    : require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/model/office-registry.        http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Comment: @Zefiryn Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier;  class is missing

Comment: after i have done this i am getting the shipping methods as text box and also text box for each shipping method so please help me here

Comment: if any one have Carrier class code please fwd me

Comment: @sangan Carrier model is pretty simple as it does not influence the checkout except the plugin that relies on values for carrier and method code. I included it in the answer

Comment: Great Stuff! Any chance to have event class? The one which copies quote_address to saes_address

Comment: Getting this error
Fatal error: Class Vendor\Module\Model\OfficeManagement contains 1 abstract method and must must therefore be declared abstract or implemen the remain methods
(Vendor\Module\Api\OfficeManagementInterface::fetchOffices) in Vendor\Module\Model\OfficeManagement.php line 8

Comment: @Zefiryn, actually i have list of store in magento database. And want to show that store on checkout page for store pickup. Is this solution work for me? If no, can you please suggest me changes?

Comment: This error comes in console when i am selecting shipping method.

[2019-01-24 07:11:43] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5c49652f67c57; Message: Class \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\OfficeInterface does not exist {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: -1): Report ID: webapi-5c49652f67c57; Message: Class \\Vendor\\Module\\Api\\Data\\OfficeInterface does not exist at \\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Webapi\\ErrorProcessor.php:205, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \\Vendor\\Module\\Api\\Data\\OfficeInterface does not exist at \\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Reflection\\MethodsMap.php:155)"} []

Comment: I prepared it from my own working module so this approach is working. I might incorrectly change namespaces though, so you need to figure it out yourself.

Comment: for the observer to save the extension attribute to the table, should we need to follow this doc to do ?
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/tutorials/copy-fieldsets.html

Comment: @hkguile it should be possible to use fieldsets to copy selection from `quote_address` to `order_address` entity. However you need to remember to first store the value in the quote address itself.

Comment: @Zefiryn where is this observer file Vendor\Module\Observer\Model\Order ?

Answer (score 2):

I am adding new answer to expand on what was already provided previously but without distorting it.

This is the route that `QuoteAddressPlugin` was hooking into:

```
1. Magento\Checkout\Api\ShippingInformationManagementInterface::saveAddressInformation()
2. Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository::save() 
3. Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\SaveHandler::save() 
4. Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\SaveHandler::processShippingAssignment() 
5. Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingAssignmentPersister::save()
6. Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingAssignmentProcessor::save()
7. Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ShippingAssignment\ShippingProcessor::save()
8. Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::apply()
```

The last method was calling `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::setShippingMethod()` which was actually call for `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::__call()` which I used. Right now I found a better place for the plugin, it is `Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment::setShipping()` method. So the plugin part can be rewritten to:

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment">
    <plugin name="carrier-office-plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote\ShippingAssignmentPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

and plugin itself:

```
namespace Vednor\Module\Plugin\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier;

/**
 * ShippingAssignmentPlugin
 */
class ShippingAssignmentPlugin
{
    /**
     * Hook into setShipping.
     *
     * @param ShippingAssignment $subject
     * @param ShippingInterface $value
     * @return Address
     */
    public function beforeSetShipping($subject, ShippingInterface $value)
    {
        $method = $value->getMethod();
        /** @var AddressInterface $address */
        $address = $value->getAddress();
        if ($method === Carrier::CARRIER_CODE.'_'.Carrier::METHOD_CODE
            && $address->getExtensionAttributes()
            && $address->getExtensionAttributes()->getCarrierOffice()
        ) {
            $address->setCarrierOffice($address->getExtensionAttributes()->getCarrierOffice());
        }
        elseif ($method !== Carrier::CARRIER_CODE.'_'.Carrier::METHOD_CODE) {
            //reset inpost machine when changing shipping method
            $address->setCarrierOffice(null);
        }
        return [$value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Zefiryn, I came across the problem with: 
`quote.shippingAddress().extensionAttributes.carrier_office = office;`

When I get into checkout first time (new private window) as a guest (but the same occurs with registered client) attribute office is not saved into database after first "Next". Although in console I see correct output for: `console.log(quote.shippingAddress().extensionAttributes.carrier_office);`

When I get back to the first checkout page and select office again then it is saved. What could be the reason of this behavior?

I tried to use: 
`address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();
rateRegistry.set(address.getKey(), null);
rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);
quote.shippingAddress(address);`

but without success...

Answer (score 0):

@Zefiryn, Can you explain in few words how does your above plugin work?
Im little confused because as I know __call method is executed if we try execute method that not exists for particular object. It seems to be true because in app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php I dont see such method - only comment:

`/**
 * Sales Quote address model
...
 * @method Address setShippingMethod(string $value)`

1. Why do you use around interception when there is no method implementation?
2. Next I see `$subject->setInpostMachine` and `$subject->getCarrierOffice(null);` Does it mean that above plugin's method will be executed again as there is no setInpostMachine() and getCarrierOffice() method in Adress Class? It looks like loop to me.
3. From where Magento execute `setShippingMethod()`? How normally this method is used? I cant find any simillar interceptions in Magento code.

Comment: Ok, so I prepared the answer based on a module I wrote for testing, it used inpost_machine field, so this one just did not get correctly changed to carrier_office in this place. Second, at the time I was developing this module I haven't found a place where I could get both selected carrier and address with extension attributes sent except `setShippingMethod` call on `AddressInterface` object and since there is no such method then I had to use around__call to see if `setShippingMethod` was called or some other magic field. Right now I've found a better place and I will post it in new reply.